# Getting 500 response status (Internal server error) for BAD request

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I want response status to be 400 BAD Request when null or no value is passed in a list called Entries.
I created a custom validation @ValidList to achieve this. But rather than 400 BAD Request, I am getting 500 Internal Server Error in response. How can I fix this?

My class structures:

```
public class RequestAPI{
    @PostMapping(value = "/request",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity request(
        @Valid @NotNull @RequestBody(required = false) Data data) { }
}
@ValidList
public class Data extends ArrayList<@Valid Entries> { }

public class Entries {
  @NotNull
  String firstName

  @NotNull
  String lastName
}
```

Validator Classes:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = ListValidator.class)
public @interface ValidList  {
    String message() default "List cannot empty or contain null values";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}


public class ListValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidList, List<? extends Object>> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<? extends Object> list,
                           ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !(list == null || list.isEmpty() || list.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull));
        //  mark the list invalid is empty or contains any null values.
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidList constraintAnnotation) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure since you haven't shared the stack trace that generated the 500 error, but you probably need to handle the exception somehow.
Assuming that the exception is the `ConstraintViolationException`, you can catch the exception using a `@RestControllerAdvice`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleApiRequestException(ConstraintViolationException ex) {

        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

        // ...handle the exception

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Error message body", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

To know more about exception handling in Spring Web, you can refer to the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.15/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler

Comment: Thanks @joaonic for the suggestion. I also think it should have been a constraintViolationException and I had already created the solution that you suggested.  But it actually was throwing a ```MethodArgumentNotValidException```.  I added that exception in the  ```@ExceptionHandler```  and was able to get 400 response status. Thanks